# using social_share_button_tag in rails 4 application google plus customize title is not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-plus, social-networking, page-title, socialshare

I have used social_share_button_tag in my rails 4 application to share news to facebook, twitter and google plus and customized the title. The code segment is given below:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@abc.full_name,
url: "#{@abc.page}?action=xyz&record=#{@abc.id}",
desc: @abc.full_name,
popup: 'true',
'data-facebook-title' => "The news of #{@abc.full_name}",
'data-twitter-title' => "The news of #{@abc.full_name}",
'data-google_plus-title' => "The news of #{@abc.full_name}",
'data-facebook-caption' => "The news of #{@abc.full_name}"
```

) %>

For facebook and twitter it's working fine but for google plus the title is not showing. it is showing something else ( may be auto populate some default).

In the [documentation](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button)  it is clearly mentioned that:

Apart from the default title, you can specify the title for the special social network:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title, 
'data-twitter-title' => 'TheTitleForTwitter') %>
```

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google+ share endpoint API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link) only accepts `url` (the URL) and `hl` (the language code). You can't set a custom Title. To set the title you have to populate the [+Snippet](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) in the HTML of the page being shared.